# How to insert response string into file as separate lines with each word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, file-io, textinput

Is there a way to put keywords of strings you get into a text file, but as each word gets entered they each have their own line. for example :
"dog cat pig" would be:

```
"dog"
"cat"
"pig"
... and so on
```

^^^ I'm trying to make the text file look like this, instead of how it does below

I'm searching through tag list for and I would like the results to get put in a text file to have each word have its own line. Is this doable?

Here's my code:

```
getusers = client.get('/tracks', :genre => 'pop', :limit => 200 )

file = File.new("tag_list.txt","a")
array1 = []

getusers.each { |t| 
  puts t.tag_list 
  file.puts "#{t.tag_list}"
}
```

My response:

[image]

^^^ when inserted into the text file it will looked exactly how its written above.
any help/idea would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The response is hard to understand, can you add linenum for each tag_list?

Comment: that's what my response looks like in the text file @liuzxc does that help?
cause what i'm trying to do is make the text file look like the "dog cat pig" explanation at the beginning of my question..

Comment: The question is expected to stand alone, so please add any additional information to the question itself.  Also, whenever possible, please add text as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try.

```
 getusers.each { |t| 
      puts t.tag_list
      if not t.tag_list.blank?
         t.tag_list.split(" ").each do |word|
           file.puts word
         end
      end
 }
```